# JSchException: Auth fail | Apache SSHD & JCraft JSch

Tags: java, jsch, sshd, apache-mina

I'm trying to connect to a mock server using RSK keys generated using `KeyPairGenerator`.

```java
  Constructor() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException {
    KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    keyGen.initialize(2048);
    this.pair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
  }
```

My `SshServer` configuration is as follows:

```java
  @BeforeAll
  @SneakyThrows
  public void setup() {
    sshd = SshServer.setUpDefaultServer();
    sshd.setPort(authentication.getPort());
    File keyFile = new File(".tmp/host.ser");
    FileUtils.forceMkdirParent(keyFile);
    sshd.setKeyPairProvider(new SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider(keyFile.toPath()));
    sshd.setSubsystemFactories(Collections.singletonList(new SftpSubsystemFactory()));
    sshd.setPasswordAuthenticator(
        (username, password, session) ->
            username.equals(authentication.getUsername())
                && password.equals(authentication.getPassword()));
    String privateKey =
        "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
            + Base64.getMimeEncoder().encodeToString(pair.getPrivate().getEncoded())
            + "\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----";
    String publicKey =
        "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n"
            + Base64.getMimeEncoder().encodeToString(pair.getPublic().getEncoded())
            + "\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
    FileUtils.write(new File(".ssh/id_rsa"), privateKey, Charset.defaultCharset());
    FileUtils.write(new File(".ssh/id_rsa.pub"), publicKey, Charset.defaultCharset());
    sshd.setPublickeyAuthenticator(
        new AuthorizedKeysAuthenticator(new File(".ssh/id_rsa.pub").toPath()));
    sshd.start();

  }
```

And the following is my `JSch` configuration:

```java
  @SneakyThrows
  public void open() {
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    Properties config = new Properties();
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    if (StringUtils.isNoneBlank(privateKey)) {
      jsch.addIdentity(
          ".ssh/id_rsa", Objects.nonNull(passphrase) ? passphrase.getBytes() : null);
    }

    session = jsch.getSession(username, server, Objects.nonNull(port) ? port : DEFAULT_PORT);
    session.setConfig(config);
    if (StringUtils.isNoneBlank(password)) session.setPassword(password);
    session.connect();
    channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
    channelSftp.connect();
  }
```

The exception I'm getting is as follows:

```sh
Auth fail
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
    at app//com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:519)
    at app//com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
```

For some reason, the RSA keys that I generated aren't working even though they're similar to the system-generated keys. But when I created a private key and public key using `ssh-keygen -p -m pem` and used the keys from `/home/my-home/.ssh/`, it worked. It's just not working when I create the keys using `KeyPairGenerator`. Thanks in advance, any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: That's not what my public key file looks like at all. Try: `String publicKey = "ssh-rsa " + Base64.getMimeEncoder().encodeToString(pair.getPublic().getEncoded()) + " foo@bar";` That last value is probably arbitrary but formed from $USER@$HOST
That header and footer (amd more) *is* in my *private* key though

Comment: are you able to connect with the KeyPairGenerator generated keys using ssh (not jsch?). the question is whether the keys or jsch config is the problem. which jsch version are you using?

Comment: @goose and @Matthias, The problem is with the public key. When I generate the public key with `ssh-keygen -y -f .ssh/id_rsa`, it worked. Now I need to figure out a way to generate it through code.